# Are there different species that profoundly changed the earth?

Tags: species, environment, climate-change

In the narration of the first episode of the new Netflix series *Life on Our Planet* it says that one species (humans) “would go on to change our planet like nothing before.” My immediate thought was the Great Oxidation Event and how cyanobacteria changed the earth in a way far more extreme than anything humans have done.

Are there any other species that have profoundly changed the earth?

Comment: It's ironic that cyanobacteria may have ushered in the first ice age, and humans may have done the opposite.